# High quality zoom in unity terrains

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an application that uses the Unity terrain engine to view the terrain (and models on the terrain) with a few different fields of view. This is essentially a camera with telescopic zoom that transitions from 1x to 3x then to 9x.

The problem I'm having is that the various detail roll off settings (Detail Distance, Tree Distance, Billboard start etc.) are all based on the distance from the camera to the 'detail'. At 3x and 9x zoom the view starts at 200 units, and goes out to 2000 units. The landscapes look pretty rubbish, none of the grass shows up, and the trees are all billboarded (like a mid 90s game :-))

I'm trying to set a min & max range for detail based on what I can see in my viewport, not how far the camera is from that detail.

Has anybody got a suggestions as to how I can ramp up distant details when I have my tighter FOVs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try add mipmaps for all textures on scene and disable lods on objects and check new details!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are using standard size for your objects (1 unit ~ 1 meter)
2. Make sure all textures sizes are power of two and have mipmaps enabled.
3. Go to quality settings and Make sure Max LOD level is 0
4. Change LOD bias and see if it helps (1 is more details, 0 is less details)
5. Check detail distance in terrain itself and make sure it is far enough.